# How could we create "instances" of a type or record on the fly

Tags: constructor, clojure, types, dispatch

This question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748559/clojure-creating-new-instance-from-string-class-name) but i think is more general.

Recently i try to create type "instances" on the fly with multimethods (or with a unique function constructor if possible), based in a metadata tag. I linked a type (a java class under the hood) with this tag and then i didnt know how to continue in a elegant way (without eval or java reflection and strings); new is a special form and it's difficult to handle although you use macros.

In seudo-code it would be:

```
(def my-tagged-data (with-meta my-data {:my-type-tag my-ns.My-Type}))
(def factory-function [tagged-data] 
     (create (:my-type-tag (meta tagged-data)) tagged-data))
```

Comment: re-reading a comment of quoted previous question maybe the only way is modify the datatypes features of clojure :-/

Comment: Do you want to write custom factory code for each record type and associate it with the record type somehow so that you can call factory using the name of the record type (rather than the name of the factory)?

Comment: mmm exactly that was mi original idea, without a explicit factory if possible, using multimethods or protocol methods (or somewhat with dispatch) to add constructors in a extensible way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide factory functions for your types.

```
(def my-tagged-data (with-meta my-data {:my-type-factory `my-type-factory}))

(defn factory-function
  [tagged-data] 
  (@(resolve (:my-type-factory (meta tagged-data))) tagged-data))
```

This may or may not be feasible.

Comment: is the @ in front of resolve a typo or a hack unknown for me?? i had paid no attention to resolve, thank for the point.

Comment: the @ is dereffing the var returned by resolve but is optional in this case because you can directly call a var.

Comment: kotarak idea is good but instaed of a symbol you can directly put the factory into metadata and use a global registry as a fallback for legacy classes.

Comment: well, i think it is not exactly that i want but i think the response has more sense than the question and it is suggestive

Comment: @cgrand: however putting the factory directly in the metadata is more static. Changing the factory will then only affect fresh my-data's while the symbol approach also affects existing my-data's. YMMV. Also fns are not printable? Is this of interest?

Comment: @kotarak if you want that dynamicity then use the Var itself instead of its value or its symbol. Best of both worlds?

Comment: @cgrand It has its uses. But I agree. I normally try to avoid this reflection kind of stuff.

Comment: @kotarak I just gisted today a lib where I use resolve (see See http://gist.github.com/589570). My loath of resolve is exagerated but I try to avoid it as much as possible -- especially at runtime, in macros it's less harmful since we have &env.

Comment: I have a project with several models, which have to be initialised in the database (in case of a "fresh" db). Since I use clj-record for this project, I can use a simple name to retrieve things. To just name the names once, I used `resolve` to retrieve the model information for table creation etc.: `(let [desc @(resolve (symbol (str "my.project.models" model-name) "description"))] (create-table ....))`. I think this is the only case I ever used `resolve`. Maybe not the best approach, but it worked. I'm deeply suspicious about code using `resolve`, `intern` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use reflection. (Better idea than eval, I think).

Comment: Moreover, i am missing something obvious cause i dont catch how to use newInstance, cause Integer/class dont work neither (Integer/newInstance)