# Use a clojure macro to automatically create getters and setters inside a reify call

Tags: macros, clojure, reify

I am trying to implement a huge Java interface with numerous (~50) getter and setter methods (some with irregular names). I thought it would be nice to use a macro to reduce the amount of code. So instead of

```
(def data (atom {:x nil}))
(reify HugeInterface
  (getX [this] (:x @data))
  (setX [this v] (swap! data assoc :x v)))
```

I want to be able to write

```
(def data (atom {:x nil}))
(reify HugeInterface
  (set-and-get getX setX :x))
```

Is this set-and-get macro (or something similar) possible? I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Updated with a second approach -- see below the second horizontal rule -- as well as some explanatory remarks re: the first one.)*

---

I wonder if this might be a step in the right direction:

```
(defmacro reify-from-maps [iface implicits-map emit-map & ms]
  `(reify ~iface
     ~@(apply concat
         (for [[mname & args :as m] ms]
           (if-let [emit ((keyword mname) emit-map)]
             (apply emit implicits-map args)
             [m])))))

(def emit-atom-g&ss
  {:set-and-get (fn [implicits-map gname sname k]
                  [`(~gname [~'this] (~k @~(:atom-name implicits-map)))
                   `(~sname [~'this ~'v]
                      (swap! ~(:atom-name implicits-map) assoc ~k ~'v))])})

(defmacro atom-bean [iface a & ms]
  `(reify-from-maps ~iface {:atom-name ~a} ~emit-atom-g&ss ~@ms))
```

NB. that the `atom-bean` macro passes the actual compile-time *value* of `emit-atom-g&ss` on to `reify-from-maps`. Once a particular `atom-bean` form is compiled, any subsequent changes to `emit-atom-g&ss` have no effect on the behaviour of the created object.

An example macroexpansion from the REPL (with some line breaks and indentation added for clarity):

```
user> (-> '(atom-bean HugeInterface data
             (set-and-get setX getX :x))
          macroexpand-1
          macroexpand-1)
(clojure.core/reify HugeInterface
  (setX [this] (:x (clojure.core/deref data)))
  (getX [this v] (clojure.core/swap! data clojure.core/assoc :x v)))
```

Two `macroexpand-1`s are necessary, because `atom-bean` is a macro which expands to a further macro call. `macroexpand` would not be particularly useful, as it would expand this all the way to a call to `reify*`, the implementation detail behind `reify`.

The idea here is that you can supply an `emit-map` like `emit-atom-g&ss` above, keyed by keywords whose names (in symbolic form) will trigger magic method generation in `reify-from-maps` calls. The magic is performed by the functions stored as functions in the given `emit-map`; the arguments to the functions are a map of "implicits" (basically any and all information which should be accessible to all method definitions in a `reify-from-maps` form, like the name of the atom in this particular case) followed by whichever arguments were given to the "magic method specifier" in the `reify-from-maps` form. As mentioned above, `reify-from-maps` needs to see an actual keyword -> function map, not its symbolic name; so, it's only really usable with literal maps, inside other macros or with help of `eval`.

Normal method definitions can still be included and will be treated as in a regular `reify` form, provided keys matching their names do not occur in the `emit-map`. The emit functions must return seqables (e.g. vectors) of method definitions in the format expected by `reify`: in this way, the case with multiple method definitions returned for one "magic method specifier" is relatively simple. If the `iface` argument were replaced with `ifaces` and `~iface` with `~@ifaces` in `reify-from-maps`' body, multiple interfaces could be specified for implementation.

---

Here's another approach, possibly easier to reason about:

```
(defn compile-atom-bean-converter [ifaces get-set-map]
  (eval
   (let [asym (gensym)]
     `(fn [~asym]
        (reify ~@ifaces
          ~@(apply concat
              (for [[k [g s]] get-set-map]
                [`(~g [~'this] (~k @~asym))
                 `(~s [~'this ~'v]
                      (swap! ~asym assoc ~k ~'v))])))))))
```

This calls on the compiler at runtime, which is somewhat expensive, but only needs to be done once per set of interfaces to be implemented. The result is a function which takes an atom as an argument and reifies a wrapper around the atom implementing the given interfaces with getters and setters as specified in the `get-set-map` argument. (Written this way, this is less flexible than the previous approach, but most of the code above could be reused here.)

Here's a sample interface and a getter/setter map:

```
(definterface IFunky
  (getFoo [])
  (^void setFoo [v])
  (getFunkyBar [])
  (^void setWeirdBar [v]))

(def gsm
  '{:foo [getFoo setFoo]
    :bar [getFunkyBar setWeirdBar]})
```

And some REPL interactions:

```
user> (def data {:foo 1 :bar 2})
#'user/data
user> (def atom-bean-converter (compile-atom-bean-converter '[IFunky] gsm))
#'user/atom-bean-converter
user> (def atom-bean (atom-bean-converter data))
#'user/atom-bean
user> (.setFoo data-bean 3)
nil
user> (.getFoo atom-bean)
3
user> (.getFunkyBar data-bean)
2
user> (.setWeirdBar data-bean 5)
nil
user> (.getFunkyBar data-bean)
5
```

Comment: I thought I remembered Chouser demonstrating basically the same sort of use of `eval` on SO and, sure enough, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748559/clojure-creating-new-instance-from-string-class-name/3752276#3752276). The scenario under consideration there is different, but his explanation of the performance trade-off involved is very pertinent to the present situation.

Answer (score 4):

The point is reify being a macro itself which is expanded before your own set-and-get macro - so the set-and-get approach doesn't work. So, instead of an inner macro inside reify, you need a macro on the "outside" that generates the reify, too.

Answer (score 1):

Since the trick is to expand the body before **reify** sees it, a more general solution could be something along these lines:

```
(defmacro reify+ [& body]
  `(reify ~@(map macroexpand-1 body)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to [force your macro to expand first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984504/clojure-how-to-make-my-macro-expand-before-system-macros):

```
(ns qqq (:use clojure.walk))
(defmacro expand-first [the-set & code] `(do ~@(prewalk #(if (and (list? %) (contains? the-set (first %))) (macroexpand-all %) %) code)))

(defmacro setter [setterf kw] `(~setterf [~'this ~'v] (swap! ~'data assoc ~kw ~'v)))
(defmacro getter [getterf kw] `(~getterf [~'this] (~kw @~'data)))
(expand-first #{setter getter} 
 (reify HugeInterface 
  (getter getX :x)
  (setter setX :x)))
```