# Clojure - How to make my macro expand before system macros?

Tags: macros, clojure

If I do, for example:

```
(defmacro qqq [] '(toString [this] "Qqq"))
(reify Object (qqq))
```

it fails because of `reify` sees `(qqq)` instead of `(toString [this] "Qqq")`.

The [usual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434902/use-a-clojure-macro-to-automatically-create-getters-and-setters-inside-a-reify-ca/4435125#4435125) is a macro that wraps "reify" call with my own thing, but it is longer and more intrusive.

How to make my macros stronger that usual macros to be expanded first?

Expecting something like:

```
(defmacro ^{:priority 100500} qqq [] '(toString [this] "Qqq"))
(reify Object (qqq))
```

or

```
(defmacro qqq [] '(toString [this] "Qqq"))
(expand-first #{qqq} (reify Object (qqq)))
```

Comment: Pretty sure there is no such mechanism in Clojure.

Comment: @Brian Carper, But I suspect `expand-first` can be implemented externally (and later included in Clojure). Trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro that forces given user macros to expand first (requires `clojure.walk`):

```
(defmacro expand-first [the-set & code] 
 `(do ~@(prewalk 
  #(if (and (list? %) (contains? the-set (first %)))
  (macroexpand-all %)
  %) code)))
```

Who has ideas how to make it better?

Comment: `prewalk` vs `postwalk`?    `macroexpand-all` vs just `macroexpand`?

Answer (score 9):

There is a reader-macro to evaluate things at read-time (before macro-expansion time)..

```
(defn qqq [] '(toString [this] "Qqq"))
(reify Object #=(qqq))
```

I've never seen this done in "real" code, and I think most people would consider it a hack, but it's there if you need it.

Comment: Shortest version and no additional dependencies. Looks nice. What pitfalls / what `#=` is normally used for/

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
(defn reifyx [x y]
  (eval `(reify ~x ~y)))

(defn qqq [] '(toString [this] "Qqq"))

(reifyx 'Object (qqq))
```

I found an [apply-macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.apply-macro/apply-macro). I tried it, but it seems to be broken. The most important thing I gleaned from looking at `apply-macro` was that it solved the problem using `eval` just as I have.

Comment: CompilerException Unable to resolve symbol: toString in this context

Comment: Fixed code is `(eval \`(reify Object ~(macroexpand \`(qqq))))` All this "macroexpands" gets duplicated over and over if I use qqq often. Is there better fix?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to mention. `qqq` should be a function that returns a list rather than a macro.