# Clojure #= reader macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I just "discovered" the `#=` reader macro from a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984504/clojure-how-to-make-my-macro-expand-before-system-macros) on Stackoverflow 
and it solves a problem. How likely is this reader macro to become an 
official (documented) part of the language? How about deprecated or 
changed behavior?

The `#=` reader macro causes the following s-expression to be evaluated by the Lisp reader (before macro expansion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used by the core language when something is printed with *print-dup* true, so I'd wager that it is going to stay. No idea why it is not documented.

```
user=> (binding [*print-dup* true] (prn {:foo 1 :bar 2}))
#=(clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap/create {:foo 1, :bar 2})
nil
```

Comment: Thanks. I also wonder why it's not documented. It would be useful in macros to evaluate a sub-expression before the macro expands.

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented because it could go away / be replaced with something else. I wouldn't recommend using it in your programs.