# how to convert a string to a clojure expression?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to send a clojure expression in a string to be evaluated at the receiver, which might be a web service written in compojure. For example, suppose I have the string "(* 7 6)", which I'd like to turn into '(* 7 6), which I can then pass to eval and get 42. This operation is trivial in JavaScript, but not quite sure how to do it in clojure. Hints?

Comment: Beware, this would allow a web client (anyone on the internet) to execute arbitrary code in your web server process, such as redefining vars, shelling out, deleting files, etc.

Comment: Got it. My application will authenticate and authorize the sender for full trust before allowing this operation. Alternatively, it will parse, analyze, and / or sandbox the injected code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(eval (read-string "(* 7 6)")) ;; 42
```

Or, for short:

```
(load-string "(* 7 6)") ;; 42
```

Comment: I feel like this should be mentioned here; beware that even if you don't call eval, read-string itself will evaluate code:
```(read-string "#=(clojure.java.shell/sh \"ls\")")```

Comment: I didn't find documentation for the #= reader syntax. Would you be so kind as to explain it, please?  This is a very important observation!

Comment: I found the answer in the following SW question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427967/clojure-reader-macro. This is rather a big deal since it makes it impossible to prevent evaluation without writing my own reader and could ruin my plans to use clojure for safe injection.

Comment: found here how to turn it off https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/_QBcSXE2iuE

Comment: Well, I'm glad I mentioned it then. You'll probably also want to use [clojail](https://github.com/flatland/clojail) when actually executing the code.